# How can I make Flash layers chage place on Browser to see what's under them?

Tags: flash, layer

How can I move the Flash layers on the browser or 
How can I make Flash layers transperant on Browser to see what's under them ?

When browsing (I use firefox) in the internet when flash apps. work;
At flash applications some images get over the other and I want to see whats under that image.

I some how have to move that image or make it transperant to see under it, can you give me an idea of how this mystery can be solved ?

Comment: Is the embedded Flash swf inside a DIV layer? You could move it. I'm pretty sure you can't make an embedded object transparent.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the "wmode" parameter of the embed code to "transparent":

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
```